# How to avoid Numpy automatic type conversions to float64?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, floating-point

Is it possible to avoid or emit warnings for automatic Numpy type conversions from integer and `32 bit float arrays` to `64 bit float arrays`?

My use case for this is that I'm developing a large analysis package (20k lines of Python & Numpy), and currently have a mix of float 32 and 64 and some int dtypes, very likely resulting in sub-optimal performance and wasted memory, and basically I'd like to use float32 consistently everywhere.

I know that in *Tensorflow* combining two arrays of different dtype gives an error - precisely because implicit conversions to float64 would lead to bad performance and is "infectious" on all computed tensors and hard to find where it is introduced if done implicitly.

Looking for an option in Numpy or a way to monkey-patch Numpy so that it behaves in this regard like Tensorflow, i.e. emits an error on implicit type conversion on operations like `np.add`, `np.mul` etc., or even better, emits a warning with printed traceback, so that execution continues but I see where it happened. Possible?

Comment: `ufunc` like `np.add` take a `casting` parameter.  Looks like the default value is `same_kind'  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html#casting-rules,  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.can_cast.html#numpy.can_cast.  I think you want `casting='no'`.

Comment: It may also help to provide the `out` parameter.

Comment: However on testing, `np.multiply(x,2., casting='no')` gives me an error because it can't cast the `np.array(2.)` (float64) to float32 (to match `x`.  So this casting parameter may have less to do with the resulting `dtype`, and more with what works as inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I didn't test this in any serious way, but it seems to be a promising route.

A comparatively painless way of manipulating ufunc behavior seems to be [subclassing `ndarray`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.classes.html) and overriding `__array_ufunc__`. For example, if you are content with catching anything that produces `float64`

```
class no64(np.ndarray):
    def __array_ufunc__(self, ufunc, method, *inputs, **kwds):
        ret = getattr(ufunc, method)(*map(np.asarray,inputs), **kwds)
        # some ufuncs return multiple arrays:
        if isinstance(ret,tuple):
            if any(x.dtype == np.float64 for x in ret):
                raise ValueError
            return (*(x.view(no64) for x in ret),)
        if ret.dtype == np.float64:
             raise ValueError
        return ret.view(no64)

x = np.arange(6,dtype=np.float32).view(no64)
```

Now let's see what our class can do:

```
x*x
# no64([ 0.,  1.,  4.,  9., 16., 25.], dtype=float32)
np.sin(x)
# no64([ 0.        ,  0.84147096,  0.9092974 ,  0.14112   , -0.7568025 ,
#       -0.9589243 ], dtype=float32)
np.frexp(x)
# (no64([0.   , 0.5  , 0.5  , 0.75 , 0.5  , 0.625], dtype=float32), no64([0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3], dtype=int32))
```

Now let's pair it with a 64 bit argument:

```
x + np.arange(6)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<stdin>", line 9, in __array_ufunc__
# ValueError

np.multiply.outer(x, np.arange(2.0))
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
#   File "<stdin>", line 9, in __array_ufunc__
# ValueError
```

What doesn't work (I'm sure there is much more)

```
np.outer(x, np.arange(2.0))  # not a ufunc, so slips through
# array([[0., 0.],
#        [0., 1.],
#        [0., 2.],
#        [0., 3.],
#        [0., 4.],
#        [0., 5.]])
```

`__array_function__` seems to be what catches those.

Comment: can you gave us a way to block any kind of operation betwee different dtype arrays ?? I am experimenting with image-processing with OpenCV and I make a lot of mistakes that escape my eyes, I understand that numpy was create to have this feature