# Can I make a numpy ndarray's dtype immutable so it doesn't change during operations?

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to flip a switch with numpy arrays so they keep their dtype instead of using python's implicit type conversion during mathematical operations?

Example: In traditional python, I get this

```
a=np.arange(5,dtype=int)
print(a+1.1)
>>>[1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1]
```

But I want to lock `a` as `int` so that the operation would change everything to the `a.dtype`:

```
a=np.arange(5,dtype=int) # somehow lock this dtype
print(a+1.1)    
>>>[1 2 3 4 5]
```

I know I can manually reset the array after each operation as `(a+1.1).astype(int)` but I'm curious if there is a way to make the ndarray's dtype immutable?

Comment: The dtype of `a` hasn't changed.  The calculation produces a new array.  Using `np.add` instead of `+` allows more control of the result dtype.

Comment: `a += 1.1` modifies `a` itself, and doesn't change `dtype`.

Comment: a += 1.1 doesnt work ---> numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'

Comment: @hpauli what if is a = a +1.1 ? Does it changes dtype ? Any way to make it immutable ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982230/how-to-avoid-numpy-automatic-type-conversions-to-float64

Answer (score -1):

mmh:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.arange(5,dtype=int)

print(a , a.dtype)

a += 2

print(a , a.dtype)

b = a +1.1

print(b, b.dtype)

a += 1.1   # ----------> LINE 15

print(a)
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4] int64
[2 3 4 5 6] int64
[3.1 4.1 5.1 6.1 7.1] float64
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncOutputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' output from dtype('float64') to dtype('int64') with casting rule 'same_kind'
```

The comment above:

> The dtype of a hasn't changed. The calculation produces a new array. Using np.add instead of + allows more control of the result dtype.

It seems worth to note:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.arange(5,dtype=int)

print(a)

b = np.add( a, 1.1)

print(b, b.dtype)

b = np.add( a, 1.1 , casting = 'no')  ### ----> LINE 11

print(b, b.dtype)
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4]
[1.1 2.1 3.1 4.1 5.1] float64
ERROR!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncInputCastingError: Cannot cast ufunc 'add' input 0 from dtype('int64') to dtype('float64') with casting rule 'no'
```

Of course:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.arange(5,dtype=int)

print(a , a.dtype)

a = a +  2

print(a , a.dtype)

a = a +1.1

print(a, a.dtype)
```

Output:

```
[0 1 2 3 4] int64
[2 3 4 5 6] int64
[3.1 4.1 5.1 6.1 7.1] float64
```

So here `a` is promoted (??) from int64 to float64

> the promotions in NumPy will follow the schema below.

[image]

But your question is not unusual: [How to avoid Numpy automatic type conversions to float64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982230/how-to-avoid-numpy-automatic-type-conversions-to-float64)